# How to override @PropertySource which uses Json file with JsonPropertySourceFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have a configuration file as follows

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(
          value = "file:${resourcePath}/../Config/config.json", 
          factory = JsonPropertySourceFactory.class,
          ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
        @ConfigurationProperties
public class EmpRequest {
    
    private String empName;
    private String empPwd;
    private String empXnum;
    private boolean empProtected;
    
   /*Getters setters */
}
```

and to test this configuration pojo, below is the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EmpRequest.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:config.json")
public class EmpRequestTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmpRequest empRequest;

    @Test
    public void testEmpService() {
        System.out.println(empRequest.getEmpName());
    }

}
```

But this override is not working. The sysout in test class is printing `null`.

Looks like the problem is to invoke JsonPropertySourceFactory with the overridden config file. But when I debug, the JsonPropertySourceFactory is still getting invoked on `file:${resourcePath}/../Config/config.json`

Any clues on this.

Comment: Because you simply cannot override it like that. The `@PropertySource` will be parsed anyway, also a `json` isn't read by default so the `@TestPropertySourcde` is basically reading nothing as it isn't a properties file but a json file.